# Change file upload Ajax url of jquery file upload plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-file-upload

I am using jquery file upload plugin in my wordPress application,
I have just downloaded folder and include index file directly.

And it showing me problem about uploadHandler file path ( ajax url)

[image]

How do i change

```
http://localhost/wpsample/wp-admin/server/php/
```

this path to

```
http://localhost/wp-content/plugins/sample/jqueryupload/server/php
```

Comment: where is you ajax code put the ajax code in the question and how you are taking  : http://localhost/wpsample/wp-admin/server/php/  url

Comment: not sure about ajax code. it is automatically handle by plugin itself

Comment: That is the only way we need to reach out to that area and than we can modify the url - according to me